# Apache Solr PDF indexing

Tags: apache, solr

I want to index the `pdf` documents whenever it is uploaded by an application. At the time of indexing I am sending the `filename` and `fileType` in the `url` like follows

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?stream.file=/D:\apache-solr-3.3.0\example\exampledocs\Accessing_MySQL_from_IntalioBPMS.pdf&stream.contentType=application/pdf&literal.id=111&literal.fileName=Test.pdf&literal.fileType=pdf&commit=true
```

I am having the fields `fileName` and `fileType` in my `schema.xml` file as well.

After I indexed the pdf documents I do the search it shows only the `content` and `id` of the `pdf` document but not the `filename` and `filetype`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you define your schema, you must specify which fields will be stored (or retrievable upon search). In this case, it is likely that your filename and filetype fields are only indexed and not stored.

Make sure your schema is like the following:

`<field name="filename" type="{yourDesiredType}" indexed="true"`**`stored="true"`**`/>`
`<field name="filetype" type="{yourDesiredType}" indexed="true"`**`stored="true"`**`/>`

For more information about editing the `schema.xml`, go to http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Yes i already mentioned like above but still not working

Comment: Any other suggestions ? Please help me